# How to define my entire network with address range or subnet mask

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I need to define my entrie network to the trusted zone. I woud like to ask, how to do this:

If i have many network like:

10.30.1.1 - 10.30.1.254
 10.30.2.1 - 10.30.2.254
 10.30.3.1 - 10.30.3.254
 10.30.4.1 - 10.30.4.254

etc...

May i define all my network like this:

10.30.1.1 - 10.33.4.254

Or

10.30.0.0/255.255.255.0

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is supernetting/CIDR (Classless inter domain routing). Instead of splitting a network into smaller parts, you group every adjacent network together.

What you do, to achieve this is convert every network address in binary, and compare up to which digit every network address matches. convert those bits back to decimal and you have your supernet.

(Or use an online calculator like http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php)